# will_paginate not working on records retrieved with find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm typing this in console:

```
user.bookmarks.page(1) 

-> ok

Bookmark.find([21, 23]).page(1)

-> undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x5b2b3a0>
```

Also tried using the paginate method: `Bookmark.find([21, 23]).paginate(page: "1")` , with the same outcome.

Any idea what goes wrong in here?

Comment: if you use find, it means you know exactly what you expect, that's why a (non chainable) Array is retrieved

Comment: isn't `user.bookmarks` also an array? (`user.bookmarks.class   => Array`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
Bookmark.paginate(:conditions => {:id => [21,23]}, :page => 1)
```

Or Simpler:

```
Bookmark.where(:id => [21,31]).page(1)
```

Comment: cool, this works for me, thanks. I'm still puzzled though to why it's not working with find.

Comment: @apneadiving answered that in the comment.  Try this and it might make it clearer:  Bookmark.find([21,23]).class and Bookmark.where(:id => [21,32]).class

Comment: k, that shows an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but `user.bookmarks.class` shows an Array. Oh well, strange stuff, but i'm not gonna dig further into this.

Comment: Right, you can call additional methods on a relation, but not an array.  With the relation, you could order, add additional where clauses, joins, includes, etc -- the pagination works off of relations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 3 or above, will_paginate/array needs to be loaded explicitly in config/application.rb to paginate array (with Bookmark.find or Bookmark.all)